# oo.load throwing "undefined is not a function"

Tags: google-analytics, requirejs, parse-platform, gulp-watch, oocharts

I am building an app using requirejs, parse.com, list.js, and using gulp to serve it. I am trying to use ooCharts to load in google analytics charts.

the failing code is written in a script tag in the html being injected on the DOM via a Parse(Backbone, essentially) View. The failing code is :

```
  <div data-oochart="bar" data-oochart-start-date="30d" data-oochart-metrics="ga:visits,Visits,ga:newVisits,New Visits" data-oochart-dimension="ga:continent" data-oochart-profile="{{id number}}"></div>

window.onload = function(){

    oo.setAPIKey("{{my api key}}");

    oo.load();
};
```

In my actual code I do have the api key and id number plugged in.

First of all, the `window.onload` won't fire at all. secondly, when i get `oo.load()` to run, my console error is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" and points to oocharts.js line 188. `oo` (the object given to access the functions in oocharts.js) is globally available, and is available before the function runs, so the view definitely has access to `oo.load()`

I also ran into a similar problem trying to use the google embed API to load in charts from my analytics. Can anyone help me with this? I believe there is some sort of conflict preventing my existing code base (the majority of which I didn't write) from working with google analytics/oocharts, but for the life of me I can't figure out where.

Comment: Where is object oo created?

Comment: it's in the oocharts.js, which I load in with require. oo.setAPIKEY works fine, but not oo.load

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone else runs into this problem:

`oo.load()` was calling `google.load()` which was not loaded onto the page by ooCharts (for whatever reason, I don't see it mentioned in the docs that it doesn't get the `google` methods it needs) so I was able to fix it by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

into the head of the HTML.